# mysql -- strange mysql varchar into excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

i have managed to build a simple apps to export mysql data into ms.excel.
but i do have a problem,
why  varchar in mysql converted into some strange string in Ms.Excel.
i.e
i have a record with value 0601133941193455
but in Ms.Excel it appears to be like this 6,01134E+14

the query is just a simple query

```
   $a= $this->db->query ("Select field from table
    where cast(sdate as date) as X between 'sdate' and 'enddate'
")
```

thanks beforehand

Comment: or add single quote `'` before the number if you want to keep the trailing 0

Comment: MS Excel has this annoying tendency of displaying numeric values without leading zeroes and displaying using scientific format unless you explicitly tell it to set the value as a string or use a number format mask.... but you don't say ___how___ you're creating this file? Are you just creating a CSV or HTML markup in a file, or are you creating a native format BIFF of OfficeOpenXML file? If the latter, what library are you using?

Comment: i Use PHPExcel library for codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select CONCAT('=\"',field,'\"') as field from table
where cast(sdate as date) as X between 'sdate' and 'enddate'
```

This should definitely work....

Comment: it result an error : syntax error, unexpected '',field,'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)